# Dynamically change the authorization method challenge scheme for asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer, and a couple of other OpenID Connect providers. When I connect my ASP.Net Core application to my IdentityServer, I include this code in my `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://myIdentityServer";
    options.ClientId = "myClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "myClientSecret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

So far, so standard. The problem is that my application will be running on several different URLs. For example, I can have an instance running under https://foo.example.com, and another one under https://bar.example.com . For each of these, I want to use a different client. So I started with adding another OIDC registration in my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", ...)
.AddOpenIdConnect("anotherregistration", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://myIdentityServer";
    options.ClientId = "mySecondClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "anotherClientSecret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

I am having trouble with finding out how to have my ASP.Net Core application decide which OIDC registration to use based on what URL the application is running on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself. There's an interface called `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` that you can overwrite. My code is as below. `GetRequestSchemeAsync()` is what does most of the work. This code assumes your OIDC registrations are the same name as the subdomain. So with subdomain `foo`, you need a registration `AddOpenIdConnect("foo", ....)`

```
public class SubdomainAuthenticationSchemeProvider : AuthenticationSchemeProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomAuthenticationSchemeProvider(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetRequestSchemeAsync()
    {
        // Get the subdomain for the host the request came from. Assumes no WWW in the string.
        var subdomainName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];

        return GetSchemeAsync(subdomainName);
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync() => await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ;

    public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultChallengeSchemeAsync() =>
        await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
        await base.GetDefaultChallengeSchemeAsync();

    public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultForbidSchemeAsync() =>
        await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
        await base.GetDefaultForbidSchemeAsync();

    public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultSignInSchemeAsync() =>
        await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
        await base.GetDefaultSignInSchemeAsync();

    public override async Task<AuthenticationScheme> GetDefaultSignOutSchemeAsync() =>
        await GetRequestSchemeAsync() ??
        await base.GetDefaultSignOutSchemeAsync();

}
```

After this, add it to the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider, SubdomainAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
```

Comment: Please share the GetSchemeAsync definition.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you need set different **callback paths** for each OpenIDConnect entry. This is the unique URL that each one is listening on, for the incoming requests form IdentityServer.

Like this example:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
  //...
 options.CallbackPath = "/app1-signin-oidc";

} 
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
  //...
 options.CallbackPath = "/app2-signin-oidc";

}
```

The three paths that you need to configure are the following (defined in the OpenIdConnectOptions class)

```
public OpenIdConnectOptions()
{
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
    SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
    RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc");
```

When a user clicks on the "sign-in" button, you can select what sign-in scheme to use, like this:

```
HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, user, authProperties);
```

Comment: Thanks. While this is something I have now fixed it doesn't solve my main issue of changing the challenge scheme on a per request basis.